# POST being sent as a GET

Tags: php, apache-flex, post

I'm writing a Flex application that uses HTTPService to communicate with a php script, in order to do a query on a database.
Everything works fine if i use a GET request, but it doesn't work with POST. For some odd reason, the php script is actually receiving a GET request instead of POST. Also, it seems not to carry the parameters that i sent from the flex app.

Here is a part of the Flex code:

```
<mx:HTTPService id="userRequest" url="url" 
                useProxy="false" method="POST" result="checkTransmissionCode()"> 
    <s:request xmlns=""> 
        <transmissionCode>{transmissionCode_TextInput.text}</transmissionCode>              
    </s:request>        
</mx:HTTPService>

private function sendCode() :void{
     userRequest.send();
}

private function checkTransmissionCode() :void {                                                                            
            if(userRequest.lastResult.authorization=="correct"){
                this.currentState='transmission';
            }
            else{
                Alert.show("Invalid");  
            }
            userRequest.clearResult();                              
        }
```

I've already found some other threads of people with a similar problem, but none of them helped me with this...
Does anyone knows why this is happening, or have any idea on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing should work.  Are there any redirect in place on the server side?  I believe those would change the request type from a Post to a Get.

In the Flex 2 days, before the method attribute was added to the HTTPService tag; I experienced odd issues, when accessing YouTube REST APIs.  It needed get requests, but the default for HTTPService was post.  I Was able to get around this by specifying a HTTP Header to GET instead of POST.  Perhaps you can use the same approach, but in reverse.

Try something like this before making the call:

```
private function sendCode() :void{
 userRequest.headers['X-HTTP-Method-Override'] = 'POST';        
 userRequest.send();
}
```

Comment: I'm just sending the request from the app on my pc, straight to php script on the web, without redirecting anything.
I also tried specifying the method to POST as you said, but it didn't work.
I've read in some pages that when i send an empty POST on flex, it is converted to GET. But even sending the POST with some parameters, the php script is getting an empty GET